# Solution structure -- subfolders or subprojects

Tags: visual-studio, software-design

I am creating a solution with Visual Studio 2017. Within this solution, I have several subfolders which each contain source code for different components of the solution.

The main solution basically contains a pre-processor, which invokes the required component(s) depending on the file arguments provided.

```
foreach (string arg in args) 
{
  switch (arg)
  {
    case "ASN":
      ASNComponent.EntryPoint.Run();
      break;
    case "INV":
      INVComponent.EntryPoint.Run();
      break;
    case "ORD":
      ORDComponent.EntryPoint.Run();
      break;
    default:
      throw new Exception("The specified component doesn't exist");
  }
}
```

The solution is structured like so:

```
MainSolution
|__ App.config
|__ Program.cs
|
|__ ASNComponent
|   |__ EntryPoint.cs
|   |__ Other files
|
|__ INVComponent
|   |__ EntryPoint.cs
|   |__ Other files
|
|__ ORDComponent
    |__ EntryPoint.cs
    |__ Other files
```

Currently, the solution only consists of the one project, with each component stored in its own subfolder and using its own namespace, which is then included by `MainSolution` with a `using` directive.

Is there any benefit to using additional Projects instead of just subfolders for `ASNComponent`, `INVComponent` and `ORDComponent`? Functionally does it even make a difference?

Comment: Breaking up a large project into sub-projects forces modular design (good for maintainability), gives opportunity for re-use and can significantly cut down on compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Using projects grant you an improved level of granularity when it comes to solution management. For example, each project can have its own references so if different projects need different ones, you don't have to include each assembly for everything. Moreover, you can choose a different project type for each project in the solution so if you're writing something complex enough that you are working with multiple languages, you can build everything when you build the solution. Additionally, each project can have a separate build directory. I'm sure there are plenty more examples of the benefits to using projects, these are just a few to demonstrate my point.

From the code you've provided, it looks like folders will suit your needs since you're trying to organize what code is executed in a single case of a switch instead of say creating a product, and building a WiX installer for that product. This would be an example of two components in one solution that would warrant their own projects.